# Why doesn't flask session object need to be instantiated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-frameworks

Reading the documentation I understand that flask defines a class flask.session.

The thing that confuses me is that when people use it they don't instantiate an object of the session class, but use session directly, as in the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['key'] = 'value'
```

I don't understand why the code shouldn't look something like this instead:

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
s = session() # so s is an instance of the flask.session class

@app.route('/')
def index():
    s['key'] = 'value'
```

I am also wondering if this has anything to do with session being a proxy, as it says in the documentation. I read the 'Notes on Proxies' but couldn't understand much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome question.

It gets initialized in flasks `globals.py`

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/globals.py

```
session = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_req_object, 'session'))
```

So when you import from flask you import from its package `__init__.py` which pulls session from `globals.py` and initializes it. You grab a reference to that when you directly import it.

I should clarify that session itself is not a class. It’s an instance of the LocalProxy class, which is a proxy to the request context.

Comment: Thanks! I am still a little confused about session being a class or an instance. If I do `type(session)`, I can verify what you said about it being an instance of LocalProxy. But in the documentation (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.session) flask.session is defined as a class, but in the comments below it's referred to as an object...

Comment: yeah, that is misleading isnt it. hmm.